# Using sed to change multiple lines in a file

Tags: sed

So, I'm trying to modify /etc/resolv.conf for load balancing purposes. So let's say that resolv.conf looks like this:

```
search server.com
nameserver 192.1.168.0
nameserver 192.1.168.1
nameserver 192.1.168.2
```

The goal is to have the primary server different based on this script below. So if the last octet of the IP address of a server mod 6 = 1, then resolv.conf would look like this:

```
search server.com
nameserver 192.1.168.2
nameserver 192.1.168.0
nameserver 192.1.168.1
```

Here's part of the script to do the load balance

```
# Load balance
LAST_OCTET_OF_IP=`/sbin/ifconfig -a |grep "inet addr" |grep 128|cut -d : -f 2|cut -d" " -f1|cut -d'.' -f 4`
MOD6_IP=$(( $LAST_OCTET_OF_IP % 6 ))

if [ $MOD6_IP -eq 1 ]
    # need this part

if [ $MOD6_IP -eq 2 ]
    # need this part
```

How can I use SED to replace multiple lines in this example?

Comment: Why did you choose `sed` specifically for this job over any other tool?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how important it is to use `sed`.

How about using this logic:

1. get the first line that's always the same: `search server.com`
2. add to that the right line you want
3. add to that `nameserver` lines except the one you added already

Something like this:

```
LAST_OCTET_OF_IP=`/sbin/ifconfig -a |grep "inet addr" |grep 128|cut -d : -f 2|cut -d" " -f1|cut -d'.' -f 4`
MOD6_IP=$(( $LAST_OCTET_OF_IP % 6 ))
{
grep ^search /etc/resolv.conf
grep $MOD6_IP$ /etc/resolv.conf
grep -v $MOD6_IP$ /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver
} > /etc/resolv.conf.new
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your answer, sorry I meant to reply sooner.

I ended up not using sed after all (sed was recommended to me, but I still couldn't figure it out using it).
So, I ended up doing it this way:

if [ $MOD6_IP -eq 1 ]

then

cat <<\EOF>/etc/newresolv

search server.com

nameserver 192.1.168.0

nameserver 192.1.168.1

nameserver 192.1.168.2

EOF

fi

if [ $MOD6_IP -eq 2 ]

then

cat<<\EOF> /etc/newresolv

search server.com

nameserver 192.1.168.1

nameserver 192.1.168.2

nameserver 192.1.168.0

EOF

fi

cp /etc/newresolv /etc/resolv.conf